# Always showing 53*25 mid left of screen windows 10

Tags: windows-10, display

I don't have much description of the problem. But when I started my windows 10 PC I started seeing 53*25 and it's not disappearing. I'll attach the [Screenshot of how it is displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/psAKo.jpg)screenshot.
I am not sure if this is the right place to ask. If not can you redirect to the same.

Comment: That’s a tooltip. They sometimes stick, for whatever reason. Are you using any terminal emulator/SSH client?

Comment: @DanielB I am using `mobaXterm` ssh client but even after closing everything I still see this. Is there any way I can remove it.